# vsftp "Access is denied" when writing as an authenticated user

Tags: permissions, ftp, file-permissions, vsftpd

I have set up vsftpd for private FTP. Only authenticated users in the `ftp` group can login.
Also, every user is chrooted to its home directory (`/home/username`)

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

I can log in, browse, download, but I'm not allowed to upload files. I get `550 Access is denied` message from Windows Explorer

In order to tweak I did the following:

I made sure that the directory is user-writable (`chmod g-rwx o-rwx u+w -R /home/username`), I chose to do g-rwx otherwise it could be accessible via SSH by people in the `users` group that don't get chrooted. I made sure that directory and children elements are owned by user (forced `chown -R` as root) but they didn't help.

I found no useful thing in `/var/log/messages` file. I believed that vsftpd runs as the logged in user and I found confirmation running `htop`.

What kind of permission problem could cause this behaviour? If I go with SFTP with the same user I can do everything I want!

Thank you

Comment: SELinux? I believe that you either don't have it or you have disable it, right?

Answer (score 2):

There should be an option named `write_enable` in the configuration file.

As stated [in the manpage](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html):

```
write_enable
   This controls whether any FTP commands which change the filesystem are allowed or not. These commands    
   are: STOR, DELE, RNFR, RNTO, MKD, RMD, APPE and SITE.

   Default: NO
```

it defaults to **NO**, so that might be the cause.

Comment: Already active...

Comment: @djechelon Are you using `virtual users`?

Comment: No they are all local UNIX users with each its own home directory. I have set up one so far...

Comment: @djechelon Aa side note, try looking also into `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/daemon[.log]` for errors